# Unable to set the frame of UITableViewCell's contentView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Im trying to set an offset of the contentView of my UITableViewCell. But failed. As you can find in the picture, there is no offset.

[image]

The corresponding code is as following.

**MyCell.m**

```
#import "MyCell.h"

@implementation MyCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
    UIView *backGroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height)];
    [backGroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [self addSubview:backGroundView];

    UIView *frontView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height)];
    [frontView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height)];
    myLabel.text = @"My Cell";
    myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [myLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [frontView addSubview:myLabel];

    [self.contentView addSubview:frontView];


    [self bringSubviewToFront:self.contentView];

}
return self;
}
```

**MyTableViewController.m**

```
#import "MyTableViewController.h"

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCell";

MyCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

CGPoint center = cell.center;
center.x = cell.contentView.bounds.size.width/2 - 20;
[cell.contentView setCenter:center];

NSLog(@"origin.x :%f ,y :%f, width :%f, height :%f",cell.contentView.frame.origin.x, cell.contentView.frame.origin.y, cell.contentView.frame.size.width,cell.contentView.frame.size.height);

return cell;
}
```

**log**

```
2012-08-31 18:29:34.075 TableViewCellOffsetTest[16169:207] origin.x :-20.000000 ,y :0.000000, width :320.000000, height :44.000000
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "trying to set an offset of the contentView" - there is nowhere anything in your code about offset...

Comment: Show us your code relating to [cell.contentView setCenter:center];

Comment: @user387184 Actually i would like to drag the cell.contentView horizontally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show us your code relating to [cell.contentView setCenter:center]; I suspect you're trying to move the main view of the cell. I wouldn't do that I would add a subview and offset that and add your content views to it. As you're already using a custom method all your changes need to be made there. In addition it's worth noting that you would also want to reset the cells offset each time it's reused as you'll end up moving the content further and further along.

Comment: center is a property of cell.contentView.